# ldd command show version require by so file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc, g++, dynamic-linking

```
root@PC-aic:~/sam/# ldd libEncoderFilter.so
./libEncoderFilter.so: libva.so.1: version `VA_API_0.34.0' not found (required by ./libEncoderFilter.so)
```

I knew this is because libva.so need to be the same version as mentioned.

But I want to know who decides I need this version to work? (which phase?)

Where can I see the `VA_API_0.34.0` information from libva.so.1?

Is there any way that I can solve this problem without compilation?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can solve a problem without compilation. Let's try to use [patchelf](https://github.com/NixOS/patchelf)